# Ajax- Why do I get an error function instead of success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I don't understand why is my code running the error function instead of success. I keep getting this from my console.log

`Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

I could not think of any reason why won't it execute my logic so I tried putting a redirect in my error function and this is what I get

`Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`
Basically the same thing happened so as of now I don't really have an idea as to what my problem is after editing the `windows to window`.
This is my code in js

```
function login(){
var username = document.getElementById("userID").value;
var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
var postData = { "userID": username, "Password": password };
var postJSON = JSON.stringify(postData);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/login", // server url
    type: "POST", //POST or GET
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: postJSON, // data to send in ajax format or querystring format
    datatype: "JSON",

    success: function(response) {
        alert('success');
        console.log(response);
        window.location.replace("http://localhost/index.html");
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('error');
        console.log(response);
        window.location.replace("http://localhost/index.html");

    }
});
}
```

This is my html code. I am using onclick.

```
 <input class="button" type="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" onclick="return login()"/>
```

So exactly what went wrong in my code? I am trying to call my login api (localhost:3000/api/login) through ajax with post which would then check mongodb for correct entries and output Login Success which then redirect to another page if input is correct and stay on the same page if input is wrong by giving output "Invalid Login ID or Password".

**UPDATE:**

**Server Side Code**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

var authenticate = function(db, req, callback){
var cursor = db.collection('LoginID').find({"_id" : req.body.userID, 
"Password" : req.body.Password
}).count(function(err,doc){
        if(err) return callback(err);
        if(doc == 0){
            console.log('Invalid Login ID or Password');
            return callback(null, doc);
        } else {
            console.log('Login Success');
            return callback(null, doc);
        }
    });
}
module.exports = {
postCollection : function(req,res){
    var username = req.body.userID;
    var Password = req.body.Password;
    //var createdDate =  "<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>"
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        //assert.equal(null, err);
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            res.end();
        }
        authenticate(db, req, function(err,doc) {
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            else{
                    if(!doc){
                        res.send( ' Invalid Login ID or Password ' );
                        res.end();
                    } else {
                        res.send("Login success")
                        res.end();
                    }
                }
            db.close();
        });
    });
}   
}
```

Comment: You have to resplve this `Uncaught ReferenceError: windows is not defined` first

Comment: It is window.location. No 's'. =)

Comment: @Repo I reedited it and it gives same error so my problem remains.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I reedited it accordingly and it gives the same error so my problem remains.

Comment: can you show your server side code

Comment: @farhadamjady Server side code

Comment: First, be careful: I hope your password is hashed before, because, just like that, it looks like it is stored in cleartext, which is a huge security breach. Then I assume you use express on node. Here, you only return strings as the result, which is not very clean for a REST API, but well. 
You must get a HTTP 200 as a result: that means that only your success callback should be called. To get the result, use response.responseText instead of just response. You'll get 'Login Success' or 'Invalid Login ID or Password'.

Comment: instead of `res.send()` and `res.end` use `res.json(doc)` @OngKongTat

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the success callback is only called if the HTTP return code is `2xx`.
If you send back a redirection, it is considered as an error.

The documentation mentions it:

> If the request is successful, the status
>   code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; **if
>   it results in an error (including 3xx redirect)**, they take the same
>   parameters as the error callback.

From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, statusCode section.

Moreover, you have to be careful: if an AJAX request receives a `302` response, it won't do a redirection: that is the user agent of your web browser (classic navigation) that does that automatically, but for XHR/AJAX, you have to implement it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem: as stated in the title, you don't understand why the error callback is called. You mention that you call your login endpoint on your server, and if the credentials are good, you want to redirect the user to a page. If the AJAX request gets a 302 in response, then it is normal that the error callback is called. You log the object you get in parameter, but I don't see anything wrong with this object, what do you want to get instead?

Comment: Basically I want to be able to get success function so that I can return true or false depending on the output given by the api after it has processed the input which would then redirect depending on true or false but now I keep getting error regardless of what I put in. Sorry if I was unclear

Comment: As @farhadamjady mentioned, I think we miss your code server-side: what does your server send back? What is the HTTP response code? The response code will determine which callback is called.

Comment: It sends back "Login Success" after checking against the database while "Invalid Login ID or Password" if the entry does not exist as for http response code do you mean the status code?

Comment: I recommend you to check some best practices about REST APIs and the HTTP protocol if you do not know about the HTTP response status code. FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: The html as well the other code get 200 as status code and only my index.js which is my code in js not server side gets 304. After looking at the link you recommended, I did not really understand the status code for 304.

Comment: If you see only 200 responses, then it is definitely your success callback that is called. 304 means the requested resource has not changed and it won't be downloaded: the version of the cache will be used instead.