# javascript $.ajax returns object Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

I'm getting an error returned by the alert in the error:function, notice that I also have different console.logs to know where it's going. (In this case it's going into the error:function)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );

$('#register').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "./php/register.php", 
        type: 'POST', 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            uname: $('#uname').val(),
            usur: $('#usur').val(),
            umail: $('#umail').val(),
            psw: $('#psw').val(),
            conf_psw: $('#conf_psw').val()
        },
              success:function(data){
                switch(data){
                    case "-1":
                    $('#content').load("./register.html");
                    break;

                    case "0":
                    $('#content').load("./register.html");
                    break;

                    case "1":
                    $('#content').load("./login.html");
                    break;
                }
                console.log("0");
                alert(data);
              },
              error:function(data){
                console.log("-1");
                alert(data);
              }
    });
});
/*
-1: PASSWORD NÃO COINCIDE COM A SUA CONFIRMAÇÃO
 0: EMAIL JÁ EXISTE NA BASE DE DADOS
 1: CONTA CRIADA COM SUCESSO
*/
```

});

I got this after doing what you guys said
 
from the alert:

`{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

from the echo:

`{readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Second Edit:

I checked the database and it seems its registering the values alright, I guess the error:function is called because of this:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515506/ajax-why-do-i-get-an-error-function-instead-of-success`

Third Edit:

So I tried in another browser to see if I'd get the same response, this was the response from Microsoft Edge:

Microsoft Edge feedback:

[image]

Comment: so many possibilities, can be network/backend/php/ error. `echo` the return  in the php and see what is returning

Comment: have you even try to `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: now I did, result= {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response is *probably* a js-object.
You can't simply display a js-object in an alert

You could try using `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: Note: if you want to pretty print your JSON data, use `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);`

Comment: Please don't call that a JSON object. It would be a JavaScript object. JSON is a text format. Or if you want to speak of a JSON object, it is the one you mention in your last line. Things get confusing otherwise. Otherwise put: `JSON.stringify` does not *take* JSON -- it produces it.

Comment: I got this:
{readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Comment: @dorinmunteanu Your `alert` is not in the `success` callback. I suggest you use `console.log(data)` to explore your object, and then use the property you need for your `switch-case` statement.

Comment: @Seblor how does that even work? I get different properties from different browsers, I don't think that's a solution